# Metric to measure how "standard Gaussian" a set of samples is?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution, metric

Assume that I have a set of $N\in\mathbb{R}^{D}$ samples from some otherwise unknown multivariate distribution $p$. I seek a metric which might tell me how "close" $p$ is to a standard multivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}\right)$. I am particularly interested in metrics which can pick up on tricky forms of non-Gaussianity, such as those in the [Datasaurus Dozen](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/05/the-datasaurus-dozen.html) (below).

Can you recommend any metrics which might serve this purpose?

[image]

Comment: [tag:kolmogorov-smirnov-test]?

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I wasn't aware that there are variants of that test for multivariate distributions, but apparently there are (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#The_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_statistic_in_more_than_one_dimension). Thanks!

Comment: The test isn't distribution-free in multiple dimensions, but the uniform norm on CDFs still a perfectly good metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important question is whether you want a metric that says, for example, that a Binomial(0.5, 20) distribution is close to a Normal (because obviously) or far from a Normal (because it's discrete).

Another question is whether you want a metric for all distributions or just one for empirical distributions in datasets (so everything is discrete and has  probability masses that are multiples of $1/n$.

Yet another question is how much you care about ease of computation, and in how many dimensions.

For a metric on all distributions that says the Normal and Binomial are close, you want something that metrizes convergence in distribution.  The total variation distance or the Hellinger distance would be good.

For a metric on all distributions that says the Normal and Binomial are not close, you want something based on the likelihood ratio. If it doesn't have to be literally a metric in the topological sense, the Kullback-Leibler divergence would do; if it does, you could use the symmetrised Kullback-Leibler divergence

For something that's easy to compute on data sets (but hard to work with mathematically) you could use a nearest-neighbour distance such as $\max_y\min_x d(x,y)$ for the distance between a point in one data set and its nearest neighbour in the other (that's not symmetric, you can add the same thing with $x$ and $y$ switched to make it symmetric). Or replace the $\max_y$ by a mean over $y$ or something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! That's a great answer, with a lot of nuances I didn't actively consider. I suppose the case I had in mind was the one in which the distributions likely aren't discrete, but approximated with a finite number of samples (with the hope that, as ensemble size increases $N\rightarrow\infty$, in the case $p=\mathcal{N}$, the metric would converge towards $0$). I'll look into the options you proposed! One other option I was aware of is the "Kernelized Stein Discrepancy", which is quite general, but I thought perhaps the Gaussian case yields some special solutions.

Comment: Yes, Stein-type distances would also be good, and they specialise nicely to Normal (and Poisson)